# Using $and in the pipeline for mongodb aggregate() function driver in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to work with the mongodb aggregation framework in C#.

I want to be able to put $and in my query.
Here's the mongodb query I want to run-

```
db.students.aggregate(
{
    $match:
    {
         name:"mira", 
         $and:[{date:{$gte:ISODate("2015-03-01T00:00:00")}}, 
         {date:{$lte:ISODate("2015-04-01T00:00:00")}}]
    }, 
    {
         $group:{"_id":"$subject", "$sum":"$marks"}
    }
)
```

I created match corresponding to the mongodb query but something isn't right here because I get compiler errors over the brackets.
My C# code is as follows-

```
var match = new BsonDocument { 
{ 
    "$match", 
    new BsonDocument 
    { 
         { 
            "name", "mira" 
         }
    }, 
    { 
         "$and", new BsonDocument{ {
         new BsonDocument 
         { 
              { "date", 
                 new BsonDocument { { "$gte", beginDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss") } } 
              } 
         }, 
         new BsonDocument 
         { 
              { "date", 
                new BsonDocument { { "$lte", endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss") } } 
              }
         } 
        }}
      } 
  } } ;
```

Can somebody guide me towards how to put the $and in match in my C# code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this:

```
 var match= new BsonDocument("$match", Query.And(Query.EQ("name", "mira"), 
                                                 Query.GTE("date", beginDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss")),
                                                 Query.LTE("date", endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss"))).ToBsonDocument());
```

Or you could also follow the variant that was recommended by @chridam:

```
 var match = new BsonDocument
 {
    {
      "$match",
       new BsonDocument
       {
          { "name", "mira" },
          { "date", new BsonDocument
             {
                {"$gte", beginDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss")},
                {"$lte", endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss") }
             }
          }
       }
    }
};
```

Comment: This worked for me  - var match= new BsonDocument("$match", Query.And(Query.EQ("name", "mira"), 
                                                 Query.GTE("date", beginDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss")),
                                                 Query.LTE("date", endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss"))).ToBsonDocument());

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use the **`$and`** in your **`$match`** query, this can be re-written as:

```
var start = ISODate("2015-03-01T00:00:00"),
    end = ISODate("2015-04-01T00:00:00");
db.students.aggregate(
    {
        "$match": {
            "name": "mira", 
            "date": { "$gte": start, "$lte": end}
        }
    }, 
    {
         "$group": {"_id":"$marks", "$sum":"$marks"}
    }
);
```

The **`$match`** pipeline can then be written in C# as

```
var match = new BsonDocument
 {
    {
      "$match",
       new BsonDocument
       {
          { "name", "mira" },
          { "date", new BsonDocument
             {
                {"$gte", beginDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss")},
                {"$lte", endDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss") }
             }
          }
       }
    }
};
```

Comment: I tried this and got this error - Cannot "convert from BsonDocument to bool" for the new keyword

Comment: @chridam, I think you have a litle problem in your solution, you don't need to declare a second document for `date`, check my answer. If you fix that you have my upvote.

Comment: @octavioccl You are so right, thank you for noticing. Haven't actually tested the code hence the errors, nonetheless I appreciate your input.